# How to call a js function from jquery keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function defined

```
function updateMapMarker(inputValue)
{
    geocoder.geocode({'address': inputValue}, function(results, status) 
    {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        {
            if (results[0])
            {
                placeMarker(results[0].geometry.location);
            }
            else
            {
                alert('No results found');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

And I added a keypress event into an input like this:

```
$('#tutor_singin_address').keypress(function (e)
{
    if(e.keyCode==13)
    {
        updateMapMarker( $('#tutor_singin_address').val());
    }
});
```

But console is throwing this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: updateMapMarker is not defined
```

How can I call my js function?

Comment: Is the function being defined in a scope accessible inside the event handler function?

Comment: Spelling looks correct, but double check the spelling and the case.

Comment: [seems to work here](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/muMK6/) .. there must be something wrong with your scope. if the function `updateMapMarker` is in a seperate js file, be sure to load that file before the `keypress` method

Comment: @hungerpain I doubt keypress is fired before the load of the updateMapMarker, unless it's not being loaded at all or defined in a different scope.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/piranha/keymage

Comment: Thank you all, was my mistake because I had my function declared in another function. Now is working great. :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to define an additional function to serve as the event handler:

```
function keyPressHandler(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        updateMapMarker($('#tutor_singin_address'));
    }
}
```

Then to just attach that new function as your event handler:

```
$('#tutor_singin_address').keypress(keyPressHandler);
```

I believe that your way didn't because of the tricky way JavaScript handles scoping and the `this` keyword, but I haven't confirmed it myself.  Give my way a shot!